# Android XML: L shape text view

Tags: android, xml, textview, android-xml

I have 2 TextViews:

txtView1: User first name.

txtView2: User comment.

The design should be as shown in the picture below:

[image: Desired Layout:]

The problem is that i can't find a way to implement this design without adding a third TextView.

With 2 TextViews I got either overlapped text views or side by side text views.

Any ideas?

Comment: You only need a **single** TextView to do that. Just use HTML.FromHTML to format the text (i.e.: the name in **ALL CAPS**, bold)

Comment: But left padding is not the same, the whole layout is not square.

Comment: If you don't want to overcomplicate your code, consider my suggestion: use the same left paddings.

Comment: Is that the only way I can get close to the design without reinventing the wheel?

Comment: One more thing, I cannot use 2 text colors with your suggestion.

Comment: Yes. And yes, you can have a couple of `<font-color>` tags... why not? you can use not only the `<b>` tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use even 1 `TextView` by using spans.

Here is what I got (I have only 1 text view):
[image]

And here is the code:

```
    String firstName = "Pavel";
    firstName = firstName.toUpperCase();
    String firstPart = firstName + ": ";
    String finalText = firstPart + "Text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text";

    //0 - first line margin, 50 - other lines margin. Should be taken from resources.
    LeadingMarginSpan paragraphSpan = new LeadingMarginSpan.Standard(0, 50);

    //Bold span for the first name
    StyleSpan boldSpan = new StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD);

    //Color span for the notes text. Should be taken from resources
    ForegroundColorSpan colorSpan = new ForegroundColorSpan(0x77000000);

    Spannable spannableString = new SpannableString(finalText);
    spannableString.setSpan(paragraphSpan, 0, finalText.length(), Spanned.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    spannableString.setSpan(boldSpan, 0, firstPart.length(), Spanned.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    spannableString.setSpan(colorSpan, firstPart.length(), finalText.length(), Spanned.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    textView.setText(spannableString);
```

Really recommend to get yourself familiar with [this article](http://flavienlaurent.com/blog/2014/01/31/spans/) to better understand spans

Comment: Even better than my own solution (this one uses different left paddings as well). Good job, Pavel, +1.

Comment: Works like charm.
Good job, Solved!